# How to delete a common normal map from all materials?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

So, I imported this map from somewhere in Blender and all materials seem to have a same normal map node which I want to remove. There are many materials so, if you can help me with a script to remove normal map from all materials, it would be a great gesture :) Sharing a screenshot of the same[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if mat.node_tree:
        nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
        names = [n.name for n in nodes if n.type == 'NORMAL_MAP']
        for name in names:
            nodes.remove(nodes[name])
```